# How to make folder sharing work with Parallels and Fedora 11

Tags: linux, mac, file-sharing, parallels, fedora-11

I have a Parallels installed on my Mac and I have created a Fedora 11 Virtual Machine. Everything works fine, except that the file sharing between my Mac and the VM doesn't work. On Parallels doc, they say I have to disable SELinux to make shared folders work.

How do I disable SELinux on Fedora 11?

Another thing the documentation says (and it doesn't work as well) is to configure in fstab:

```
none /media/psf prl_fs default,share 0 0
```

But when I try to mount this unit, I get a wrong fs type message.

Does anybody knows what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open `/etc/selinux/config` you will see a line that says:

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

change it to:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

to disable SELinux.

An unknown filesystem type message means the parallels file system driver is not loaded. Can you paste the output of the `lsmod` command ?

Comment: in fact prl_fs module is not installed. How do I install it?

Comment: You need to install Parallels Tools

Answer (score 1):

Inside the VM, edit the file `/etc/selinux/config` SELINUX directive to disabled, like this:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#       targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#       mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```